# if statement for columns in 2D list

Tags: python

I need to iterate two different lists of integers with an if-statement that requires a mathematic operation. I've approached this in several ways, the latest one shown below.

I have 4 lists that I've extracted from columns in a CSV file:

```
unique_names = ["Ian", "Laura", "Winona", "Garfield"]
arrivaltime = ["12:14:31", "12:15:02", "12:14:14", "13:00:00"]
score = [83, 99, 90, 100]
personalbest=[75, 100, 89, 90]
```

I need to identify the names for those competitors who are outperforming,
i.e. where the score > personalbest*1.1.

No imported modules allowed (except for csv).

```
outperforming = []
tdlist = [[arrivaltime], [unique_names], [score], [personalbest]]
for i in tdlist[2]: 
    if i*1.1 > (tdlist[3][i]): 
        outperforming.append("tdlist[1][i]")
```

I get this error: *TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'*

I also tried this to check for other errors:

```
for i in tdlist[2]: 
    if i > (tdlist[3][i]): 
        outperforming.append("tdlist[1][i]")
```

Then I get this error:  *TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list.*

Comment: Well, each element of `tdlist` is a list. So, when iterating over that list, you have lists as iterators (`i` is a list). Now, you are trying to multiply `1.1` with a list, which is not supported by python and therefore raises this error. Also, you are appending a string to your list `outperforming`, which - I think is - not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `zip()` function to group your data by index, then use an `if` to check the condition you want:

Code:

```
unique_names = ["Ian", "Laura", "Winona", "Garfield"]
arrivaltime = ["12:14:31", "12:15:02", "12:14:14", "13:00:00"]
score = [83, 99, 90, 100]
personalbest=[75, 100, 89, 90]

performers = []
for u, a, s, pb in zip(unique_names, arrivaltime, score, personalbest):
    if s > pb * 1.1:
        performers.append((u, a, s, pb))
        
print(performers)
```

Output:

```
[('Ian', '12:14:31', 83, 75), ('Garfield', '13:00:00', 100, 90)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was this close to giving up on Python. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` function to iterate over multiple sequences at once. For example:

```
for name, attempt, pb in zip(unique_names, score, personal_best):
    print(name, attempt, pb)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) solutions are certainly nice. And elegant. I would also be tempted to use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), which goes through a list and gives you the each item and the index:

```
for idx,x in enumerate(score):
    if s > 1.1*personalbest[idx]:
        outperforming.append(unique_names[idx])
```